# wanted put array list items into variables using loop

Tags: java, loops, variables, arraylist

i am dynamically adding items to array-list after i wanted to
Initialize Variables  using this array-list items
my array-list is

```
ArrayList<String> dayCountList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

i try to do like this but it doesn't work

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dayCountList.size() ;i++) {
     double day+"i" = Double.parseDouble(dayCountList.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: (   double day+"i"   )  what are you trying to do it will not work

Comment: so do u know how do this

Comment: You have to tell me what are you trying to do.

Comment: you want to name variables day0, day1, day2,...?

Comment: if you want to name the variables day0,day1 and so on as @JeremyKahan pointed then it is a wrong practice . To prevent you from  doing this arrays are provided in java use them.

Comment: Lookup how to use a HashMap in Java, it's the closest thing to what you want to achieve.

Comment: This question is not useful. You must learn how to declare a variable in java first.

Comment: "_i want Initializing Variables using this array-list item my array-list is_", can you explain that statement a bit more ? I have no idea of what you want to do. See [ask]  and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a array or array list of double type like this.

```
ArrayList<String> dayCountList = new ArrayList<String>();
.
.
double day[]=new double[dayCountList.size()];

// now use your loop like this
for (int i = 0; i < dayCountList.size() ; i++) {
               day[i] = Double.parseDouble(dayCountList.get(i));
           }
```

Now you can call your variables like day[0], for first element
day[1] ,for second and so on.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this, then you probably did not understand the purpose of array lists is. One purpose of array list is exactly to avoid creating a whole bunch of variables named `day1`, `day2`, `day3` and so on.

You seem like you want to transform every element in the array list to a doubles. Why not create another `ArrayList<Double>` or `double[]` to store the transformed elements? Instead of writing `day1`, `day2`, you can say `days.get(0)`, `days.get(1)` in the case of array lists. With arrays, you can do `days[0]`, `days[1]` and so on.

```
ArrayList<Double> days = dayCountList.stream()
                             .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                             .boxed()
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());

// or

double[] days = dayCountList.stream()
                    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray()
```

Comment: ok, i  did it using another array without creating variable  thank your comment